# How to generate regex to match access.log acording to its format config?

Tags: python, regex, apache, logging, nginx

The access.log format config may be like

```
'$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'
```

Is there a way to generate a regex to match the access.log according to it? I can write regex according to the actuall log like:

```
'112.3.194.120 - - [17/Jan/2015:20:07:34 +0800] "GET /Introdction%20to%20Guitar/1%20-%202%20-%20Choosing%20the%20Right%20Guitar-%20Right-Handed%20vs%20Left-Handed%20(3-20).mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 546849 "http://example.com/video/302/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"'
```

but I can't write regex with the format config. Could anyone help?

Comment: The simplest option is to replace every dollar followed by letters with `(.+?)`.

Comment: @georg but can you know which is the remote_addr and which is the time_local? I need to sort them out.

Comment: you can use named groups for this: `(?P<remote_addr>.+?) - (?P<remote_user>.+?)` etc.

Comment: @georg I know I should use regex group, but if the order of remote_addr and remote_user changed or the format config only have `"$http_user_agent"` and no other varibles? How to write the regex? I do not think this is a simple question but I can not understand why so many people click the down button ...

Comment: When I look back for this question, I think there are better ways to make the log easy to parse ---- jsonify it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To build an expression from the config, replace config variables like `$xxx` with named groups like `(?P<xxx>.*?)` and escape delimiter characters:

```
import re

conf = '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'
regex = ''.join(
    '(?P<' + g + '>.*?)' if g else re.escape(c)
    for g, c in re.findall(r'\$(\w+)|(.)', conf))
```

Now if you match a log entry against this expression:

```
log = '112.3.194.120 - - [17/Jan/2015:20:07:34 +0800] "GET /Introdction%20to%20Guitar/1%20-%202%20-%20Choosing%20the%20Right%20Guitar-%20Right-Handed%20vs%20Left-Handed%20(3-20).mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 546849 "http://example.com/video/302/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"'
m = re.match(regex, log)
```

your variables get captured in the `matchObject.groupdict`:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(m.groupdict())
```

result:

```
{'body_bytes_sent': '546849',
 'http_referer': 'http://example.com/video/302/',
 'http_user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36',
 'remote_addr': '112.3.194.120',
 'remote_user': '-',
 'request': 'GET /Introdction%20to%20Guitar/1%20-%202%20-%20Choosing%20the%20Right%20Guitar-%20Right-Handed%20vs%20Left-Handed%20(3-20).mp4 HTTP/1.1',
 'status': '206',
 'time_local': '17/Jan/2015:20:07:34 +0800'}
```

If there are no delimiters in your log config, you'll have to use more specific sub-patterns, not just `.*`. This can be coded elegantly in a way similar to this:

```
# variable-specific patterns
patterns = {
    'remote_addr': r'(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}',
    'body_bytes_sent': r'\d+',
    # etc
}

regex = ''.join(
    '(?P<%s>%s)' % (g, patterns.get(g, '.*?')) if g
        else re.escape(c)
    for g, c in re.findall(r'\$(\w+)|(.)', conf))
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot. But I still wonder if the log format config be like `$remote_addr$remote_user$time_local$request$status$body_bytes_sent$http_referer$http_user_agent`? Can the regex still help?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than just `.*?` then. Use a dedicated expression for each config var, for example, `(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}` for the IP address or `\d+` for bytes_sent.